# Building object files that depends on other object files

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, object-files

EDITS: Including link to my makefile

I have a main program that calls a bunch of functions defined in other source files. This is not a problem because I am using `cc -c functionSource.c` <strike>functionHeader.h</strike> and generating object files before compiling my main program with `cc main.c func1.o func2.o .... -o test.o`

I am having problems when one of my functions depends on another function.
For example:
My main program calls an shuffle function which is defined in it's own source file and the shuffle function calls a swap function which in turn is defined in it's own source file.

When i try  to generate the shuffle.o file for my main program using `cc -c shuffle.o` I get an `undefined reference to swap` error.

When I try to `cc shuffle.c swap.o` i get an `undefined reference to main` error.

Here is my [makefile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6440945)

<strike>How do I go about fixing this?</strike> 
Found the problem. I had a swap function declared inside insertionSort.h and shuffle.h but no implementations.

Comment: Why are you including a header file on the compiler line? The header file should be found by `#include "insertionSort.h"` in the `insertionSort.c` file (if the header is in the same directory, or use the right path or path environment). Also, is `swap` declared in `insertionSort.h`?

Comment: See my answer below, for what I consider a solution. Your "undefined reference" is due to the fact that you forgot to specify '-c', therefor the compiler tries to link (and is missing main). Else you're basically right with your method to generate the executable: Just generate InsertionSort.o and add it to the command line you use for linking. If you use -c to compile insertionSort.c (as you should), it's useless to specify any .o-files at the commandline.

Comment: No swap is declared in swap.h and implemented in swap.c. swap.h is #included in insertionSort.c. The makefile tutorial I was reading had all the header files listed on the complier line and I did the same.

Comment: The makefile probably has the header file on the "dependency" line, not the compiler execution line.

Comment: "makefile tutorial I was reading had all the header files listed on the complier line". Then the tutorial is wrong (BTW: do you have a link?). Header files on the command line are ignored by the compiler. Header files are pulled in by using *#include* in the source files. I wish I could point you to my own make file tutorial, but unfortunately, it is in German ...

Comment: BTW: Are you trying to write a makefile, or are you just trying to compile ypur sources at the commandline / shell?

Comment: Does `insertionSort.c` or `swap.c` contain `main()`? If not, that would explain `undefined reference to main`. If `insertionSort.c` includes `swap.h`, and `swap.h` defines the function `swap`, and `insertionSort.c` is calling `swap` with the correct parameters and spelled correctly, then you shouldn't be seeing `undefined reference to swap` error when doing `cc -c insertionSort.c`.

Comment: @M.E.L. Here is the makefile tutorial I was following [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Complex-Makefile). I am trying to write a makefile. mbratch you are right the header files are on the dependencies line. Neither insertionSort.c or swap.c contains a main.

Comment: Wow. The makefile you're trying to understand is pretty complicated for the beginning. I usuggest you have a look at this makefile http://www.glitzersachen.de/articles/kleines-make-tutorial/tricky.html#makefile-tricky-2. You should be able to understand it and modify it appropriately. Use the one before that if you don't want automatic dependency generation.

Comment: Please show what you're actually entering when you get the error and give the complete output of after your comamnd. You really do runr *make* don't you? I'm asking, because I now read *cc -c swap.o* which deon't make much sense. And your Makefile says something different.

Comment: OK. Thanks :-). I'm sure we could have found this much earlier with a more or less complete description ...

Comment: Probably. :) Either way I'm glad I posted this, I have a much better understanding of makefiles and cc now.

Comment: @YS: That's OK with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to the man page: '-c' makes the compiler generating object files only (not trying to link).

Do the following:

```
cc -c insertionSort.c     # => gives insertionSort.o
cc -c -c functionSource.c # => gives functionSource.o
cc insertionSort.o functionSource.o ...and-so-on... main.c -o test
```

It's not necessary to specify header files - it doesn't help.

BTW: If you have mor than one implementation file, it is rather useful

- (a) to learn make
- (b) stick to the convention that object files and programs should be named like th sources.

E.g:

```
foo.c => foo.o
bar.c => bar
```

etc - you get the picture.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with make.  You need to get a book on introductory C programming, that will explain how to use the preprocessor, and you need to examine the documentation for your compiler so you understand what the different compiler flags do (such as when you want to use the `-c` flag and when you don't, and what the difference is).

It's wrong to include header files (`.h` files) on the compile line.  Only source files (`.c`) should be included on the command line when building object (`.o`) files.  You should be adding the headers you need into your `.c` files using the `#include` directive: `#include "insertionSort.h"`.  If you're missing a reference to a function, then `#include` the header file that declares that function: `#include "swap.h"`.

Comment: I assumed the -c flag just creates object files. I did run man cc unfortunately I didn't understand most of what the man page said.

Comment: "I didn't understand most of what the man page said." => Not surprising. Te man page is a veritable kitchen sink of information, but unfortunately doesn't begin with the most common use cases.